# Problema de segmentation faults

Tags: c++

No logro encontrar el problema de en el código, ya que cuando ingreso
el numero de patente, salta un error en la función
`(esNumeroValido)`, que me tira un error de **segmentations fault.**

Cabe aclarar que las herramientas usadas en el código, son
las únicas que puedo utilizar para resolver el problema.

Para mayor
entendimiento lo que trato de resolver en el codigo es un programa,
para un estacionamiento, el cual c*uenta con 20 cocheras a
disposición*, y *asigna una a cada vehículo ingresado*. En el momento
que este sale, se dirige a la opcion correcta, y se le retira el
numero de cochera, para que esta quede libre, al final del dia el
programa muestra las cocheras disponibles, en caso de no tenerlas , el
programa muestra en pantalla que, estan todas liberadas.

```
    int main(){
        char opcion, condicional = 'Y';
        int totalCocheras [num] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        vector<estacionamiento> cocherasOcupadas;
        do
        {
          cout<<"I: Ingreso de vehiculo"<<endl;
          cout<<"S: Salida de vehiculo"<<endl;
          cout<<"C: Consultar cochera"<<endl;
          cout<<"F: Finalizar jornada"<<endl;
    
          cout<<"Ingrese la opcion que desea ejecutar: ";
          cin >> opcion;
    
          switch (opcion)
          {
          case 'I': 
          ingresoVehiculo(totalCocheras, cocherasOcupadas);
              break;
          case 'S':
          salidaVehiculo(totalCocheras, cocherasOcupadas);
             break;
          case 'C':
          consultaCochera(totalCocheras, cocherasOcupadas);
              break;
          case 'F':
          finalizarJornada(totalCocheras, cocherasOcupadas);
             break;
          default:
            cout<<"La opcion seleccionada no es correcta por favor reingrese";
              break;
          }
          cout<<"Desea seguir operando? Y(YES) N(NO): ";
          cin >> condicional;
        } while (condicional =='Y'); 
        
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    void ingresoVehiculo (int totalCocheras[21], vector <estacionamiento> cocherasOcupadas){
        estacionamiento vehiculo;
        vehiculo.ocupado=false;
        int i = 0;
        if(i < num){
            cout<<"Ingrese la patente del vehiculo: ";
            cin.getline(vehiculo.patente,10,'\n');
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"Ingrese hora:minutos de entrada, respetando el formato de ejemplo: ";
            cin >> vehiculo.horaMinutos;
            cin.ignore();
            validarHora(vehiculo);
            cout<<"Numero de chochera asignado: ";
            vehiculo.numCochera=totalCocheras[i];
            cout<<vehiculo.numCochera<<endl;
            vehiculo.ocupado=true;
            cocherasOcupadas.push_back(vehiculo);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"No hay lugar disponible";
        }
        
        
    
    }
    
    void validarHora(estacionamiento tiempo){
        while(tiempo.horaMinutos[0]=='\0' || not validaHoraPartes(tiempo)|| strlen(tiempo.horaMinutos)!=5) {
            cout<< "Reingresa una hora valida >: (HH:MM): ";
            cin>>tiempo.horaMinutos;
            cin.ignore();
        }
    
    }
    
    bool validaHoraPartes(estacionamiento tiempo){
        bool validacion=false;
        char hora[3]="", minutos[3]="";
        
        obtenerHora(tiempo, hora);
        obtenerMinutos(tiempo, minutos);
        
        if (horaValida(hora) && minutoValido(minutos) && validarPuntos(tiempo) && tiempo.horaMinutos[0]!='\0'){
            validacion=true;
        }
        
        return validacion;
    }
    
    void obtenerHora(estacionamiento tiempo, char hora[]){
        hora[0]=tiempo.horaMinutos[0];
        hora[1]=tiempo.horaMinutos[1];
        hora[2]='\0';
    }    
    
    void obtenerMinutos(estacionamiento tiempo, char minutos[]){
        minutos[0]=tiempo.horaMinutos[3];
        minutos[1]=tiempo.horaMinutos[4];
        minutos[2]='\0'; 
    }
    
    bool horaValida(char hora[]){
        bool validacion=false;
        int nro=0;
        
        if (esNumeroValido(hora)){
            nro = ObtenerValorEntero(hora);
            
            if (nro <= 24){
                validacion = true;
            }
        }
        return validacion;
    }
    
    bool minutoValido(char minutos[]){
        bool validacion=false;
        int nro=0;
        
        if (esNumeroValido(minutos)){
            nro = ObtenerValorEntero(minutos);
            
            if (nro <= 59){
                validacion = true;
            }
        }
        return validacion;
    }
    
    bool validarPuntos (estacionamiento tiempo){
        bool validacion=false;
        
        if (tiempo.horaMinutos[2]==':'){
            validacion = true;
            
        }
        
        return validacion;
    }
    
    
    
    
    bool esNumeroValido(char texto[]){
        bool validacion=true;
        for(int i=0; i<strlen(texto)-1; i++){
            if (texto[i]!='0' && texto[i]!='1' && texto[i]!='2' && texto[i]!='3' && texto[i]!='4' && texto[i]!='5' && texto[i]!='6' && texto[i]!='7' && texto[i]!='8' && texto[i]!='9'){
                validacion = false;
            }
        }
        return validacion;
    }
    
    int ObtenerValorEntero(char magnitud[])
    {
        int valorEntero=0, base=1;
        int tamanioValor=strlen(magnitud);
        
        for(int i=tamanioValor-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            valorEntero+= ConvertirCaracterAEntero(magnitud[i])*base;
            base=base*10;
        }
        return valorEntero; 
    }
    
    int ConvertirCaracterAEntero(char caracter)
    {
        int digito=0;
        switch(caracter)
        {
            case '1':
                    digito=1;
                    break;
            case '2':
                    digito=2;
                    break;
            case '3':
                    digito=3;
                    break;
            case '4':
                    digito=4;
                    break;
            case '5':
                    digito=5;
                    break;
            case '6':
                    digito=6;
                    break;
            case '7':
                    digito=7;
                    break;
            case '8':
                    digito=8;
                    break;
            case '9':
                    digito=9;
                    break;  
            default:
                    digito=0;
            }
        return digito;  
    }
    
    void salidaVehiculo(int totalCocheras[num],vector<estacionamiento> cocheras){
        estacionamiento cochera;
        cout<<"Ingrese la patente del vehiculo de salida: ";
        cin.getline(cochera.patente,10,'\n');
        for(int i = 0;i <cocheras.size(); i++){
            if(cocheras[i].patente == cochera.patente){
                cout<<"El vehiculo fue ingresado a la hora: "<<cocheras[i].horaMinutos;
                cocheras[i].ocupado=false;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"El numero de patente ingresado no corresponde a un vehiculo registrado"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void consultaCochera(int totalCocheras[num],vector<estacionamiento> cocherasOcupadas){
        estacionamiento consulta;
        cout<<"Ingrese el numero de cochera que desea consultar: ";
        cin >> consulta.numCochera;
        for (int i=0; i < cocherasOcupadas.size();i++){
            if(cocherasOcupadas[i].numCochera == consulta.numCochera && cocherasOcupadas[i].ocupado == true){
                cout<<"El numero de cochera ingresado no se encuentra disponible"<<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"El numero de cochera ingresado esta disponible y libre para usar"<<endl;
            }
        }
    
    
    }
    
    void finalizarJornada(int totalCocheras[num],vector<estacionamiento> cocherasOcupadas){
        for(int i=0; i < cocherasOcupadas.size();i++){
            if (cocherasOcupadas[i].ocupado = true){
                cout<<"Las cocheras ocupadas son: "<<endl;
                cout<<cocherasOcupadas[i].ocupado<<endl;
            }
            else{
                cout<<"El totalidad de las cocheras estan libres"<<endl;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Hola Cristian, deberías hacer algún debug, por ejemplo imprimir `strlen(texto)` como primera línea en esNumeroValido y ver que arroja

Comment: Este código es un galimatias. No me creo que no se pueda simplificar la solución para dar un ejemplo más pequeño. Además , falta la declaración de `estacionamiento`